# Degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta$ is a 11th primitive root of unity.

Tags: field-theory

I have not been able to find the degree of this extension: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta$ is an 11th complex primitive root of unity.

I believe it is 20, but to justify it correctly I must prove that $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, so that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)]=2$ and by the tower rule $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)][\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=2\cdot10 =20$. I have not been able to prove this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a nice and slick way to do this. We know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta): \mathbb{Q}] = 10 $. Consider the element $\alpha = \zeta + \zeta^{-1}$. It's real since $\zeta^{-1} = \bar{\zeta}$ and $z+\bar{z}$ is real for any complex number. $\zeta$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ so  $\alpha$ has degree $5$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since gcf$(2,5) = 1$, we have $[\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\sqrt{2}}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10$. Since $\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\sqrt{2}})$ is a real field, $\zeta \notin \mathbb{Q(\alpha,\sqrt{2}})$ so we can conclude that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta):\mathbb{Q} ]= 20.$

Comment: How do we see that $\zeta$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$? Just because we can not represent $\zeta$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ itself? Also, how does $[\mathbb{Q(\alpha,\sqrt{2}}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10$ follow only from $\gcd(2,5)=1$? Sorry for stupid question :-)

Comment: @Diger Question $1$: Certainly $\zeta \notin \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is a subset of the real numbers. So $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. So to justify my claim, you only need to find a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\zeta$ as a root. The polynomial $x^2 - \alpha x +1.$

Comment: For Question 2, you can find this on any book that talks about galois theory. If you're at a place where you're trying to answer the question the OP asked, you should know this fact.

Comment: Regarding the second question. I guess you can, but do you mind elaborating? I mean I believe it has to do with $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=5$. Fair enough, but what would happen if you consider $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,2^{1/5}):\mathbb{Q}]$ instead. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/5}):\mathbb{Q}]=5$ and $\gcd(5,5)=5>1$, what would this imply? I would still argue that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,2^{1/5}):\mathbb{Q}]=5^2=25$, or not?

Comment: @Diger I may not have made it clear but it is indeed the case that you can conclude  $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,2^{1/5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10$ right from $\gcd(2,5) = 1 $.

Comment: $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,2^{1/5}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10$ or $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,2^{1/2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10$ ?

Comment: Woops. That was a typo. Yes, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 10 $ is what I meant.